# How to set an S4 method for 2+ classes?

Tags: r, r-s4

I would like to set a method for 2+ classes, and also enable to pass additional argument.

The 2 classes :

```
# Classes
methods::setClass(
  Class = "A",
  slots = list(
    x = "character"
  )
)
methods::setClass(
  Class = "B",
  slots = list(
    x = "character"
  )
)
```

The method dispatch should be done only for one object (the `object` argument, which is set as the `signature` of the generic). The Generic :

```
# Generic
methods::setGeneric(
  "method1",
  def = function(object, additionalArg) base::standardGeneric("method1"),
  signature = "object"
)
```

The method should make use of the object slot, and also the `additionalArg` if it is passed. The Method :

```
# Method
methods::setMethod(
  "method1",
  signature = c(
    "A",
    "B"
  ),
  definition = function(object, additionalArg = NULL) {
    print(glue::glue("Object slot : {object@x}"))
    if (!is.null(additionalArg)) {
      print(glue::glue("Additional argument : {additionalArg}"))
    }
  }
)
```

However, the `setMethod` fails, even though the signature is set to the `object` argument, and both the generic and the method implementation for objects of class `A` and `B` contain the `object` and `additionalArg` arguments.

The error :

```
Error in matchSignature(signature, fdef) : 
  more elements in the method signature (2) than in the generic signature (1) for function ‘method1’
```

Edit:
This happens also with the generic and the method having only "object" as argument, so it is not due to having more than 1 argument.

Comment: FYI, try using `message` instead of `print` for these kinds of debugging outputs, it works better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only set one method at a time. If you make two separate calls to `setMethod` (one for `A` and one for `B`), using the same function definition each time, then you will have no problem.

Alternatively, you can call `setClassUnion` to create a *class union* of `A` and `B`, and use that class union in your call to `setMethod`.

Comment: Thanks ! 
So we cannot run `setMethod` for more than 1 class.
Either it is run separately for each class (causes duplication, but ok for small function definitions), or for a composite class priorly set via `setClassUnion`, or for a class from which both classes inherits, or for all classes via using ANY.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Interestingly, for some generic functions (*group generics*), you can set methods for all of them at once, but never for multiple different signatures for the same generic.